# How do I format output of stat command last modified to mmm dd yyyy

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have tried to get output of stat command like so.

```
stat --printf "\tLinks:%h, owner:%U, group:%G, size:%B, modified:%y" $FSTAT;
```

problem is, I get the output like this

```
 modified:2020-03-14 22:20:13.528449891 -0400
```

the modified is already set to %y (human readable) but it is not pleasant. Any way to make it show as mmm dd yyyy

Comment: I suggest to switch to GNU find.

Answer (score 1):

Use the output of `stat` for input to `date`:

```
FSTAT=file.to.show
date --date="@$(stat -c "%Y" "$FSTAT")" -Idate
```

This will print date in your locale's date format. If you really want to enforce a fixed format, use a format. `man date` will tell you more.